# When is 'que' needed after 'mais' ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

I saw this on social media:

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne pouvais acheter que des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom...qu'achèterais-tu ?

I was confused by the *mais que*. I've never seen that before. Is the "que" *necessary* there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "que" serves as the *2nd* "si":

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars americains, mais **si** tu ne pouvais acheter que des choses commencant par la premiere lettre de ton prenom...qu'acheterais-tu ?

... in order to avoid the repetition of "si", "quand" etc.

This "que" usage also applies to "lorsque", "bien que" etc which already include "que" in their words.

Comment: Les "si" n'aiment pas les "rais" → *mais si tu ne pou**v**ais acheter...*

Comment: Indeed! I c&p'ed the sentence, wasn't paying attention.

Comment: Je me demande si ce n'est pas "pouvait" aussi dans la phrase originale: "Si tu pouvais, mais que tu ne pouvais" parce que le "que" n'est pas relatif au million mais au "si". (@jlliagre) ?

Comment: @Alone-zee Hi, I'd say "Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne pouvais acheter etc." but "Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne pourrais utiliser seulement pour etc." because in the second sentence, "que" is relative to the million dollars.

Comment: @lemon I would rule out *mais que tu ne pourrais* here, it should also be *pouvais* here. The conditional is possible in *Je savais que tu ne pourrais pas avoir un million de dollars*.

Comment: @lemon Hi. I should have been more precise in my wording. The construction I had in mind was: "Quand bien même tu ***pourrais*** ..., et qu'il ***pourrait*** ...".

Comment: But we have the "si"... so *si je savais que tu ne pouvais* and *si je savais que tu ne pourrais* have a different meaning. But in the question here, there is no expected "added conditional" aspect. @jlliagre and Alone-zee... probably I should ask a new question about that, don't you think?