# "Que" as a conjunction and tense sequencing

Tags: conjonctions, subordonnées, conditionnel, concordance-des-temps

This question comes from this [one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/when-is-que-needed-after-mais) and the comments below the answer.

The sentence is the following:

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne **pourrais** acheter que des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom...qu'achèterais-tu ?

But I think it should be:

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne **pouvais** acheter que des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom...qu'achèterais-tu ?

because "que" is used here as a conjunction and not a pronoun, so that "que" is at the same level as "si".

If it was used as a pronoun, we can have:

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne **pourrais** utiliser que pour des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom...qu'achèterais-tu ?

Am I right? What are the rules in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, here the conjunction *que* is used in place of *si*, so the same grammatical rules apply regarding tense and mood. *Si*, and *que* when it stands for *si*, cannot be followed by a conditional verb. (This rule is not systematically followed in colloquial speech, but it's still a rule — people who break it are generally aware that they're transgressing.) The correct and idiomatic sentence is

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne ***pouvais*** acheter que des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom... qu'achèterais-tu ?

A relative clause takes the same tense and mood as its parent clause, barring other factors. So:

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne ***pouvais*** utiliser que pour des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom... qu'achèterais-tu ?
>
> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais qui ne ***pouvaient*** être utilisés que pour des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom... qu'achèterais-tu ?
>
> Si j'avais trouvé quelqu'un qui en était capable, ce serait fait.

One other factor is if the relative clause itself is conditional relative to its parent clause. Contrast:

> Si j'avais trouvé quelqu'un qui avait une voiture, je lui aurais demandé de me raccompagner.   *(Assuming somebody is found, “avoir une voiture” is an immediate quality, so the relative clause is in the same tense.)*
> Si j'avais trouvé quelqu'un qui aurait pu me raccompagner, je lui aurais demandé de le faire.   *(Assuming somebody is found, the relative clause is a hypothetical capability, so the relative clause is in the conditional mood.)*

This level of nesting is uncommon in ordinary speech. Rather than use a relative clause, it feels more natural to say either the original sentence or

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne pouvais les utiliser que pour des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom... qu'achèterais-tu ?

Comment: Very good answer but you can not say si j'avais trouvé quelqu'un qui aurait pu me ramener. Even for a hypothetical relative you have to say si j'avais trouvé quelqu'un qui avait pu me ramener. Or to insist on the nested condition, use a comma or a conjonction : si j'avais trouvé quelqu'un, qu'il avait pu me ramener...

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional instead of imperfect in a clause headed by *si* is an exceedingly common error of informal/oral French, and that's quite simply what you've got going here (The mnemonic you often hear in quebec goes "*Les scies (si) mangent les raies*"). It's entirely possible (even probable, as much as I dislike it) that eventually this will be considered the correct usage.