# Fonction du mot « que » dans « si tu es sourd mais que … »

Tags: conjonctions, subordonnées, coordination

En lisant un livre j’ai rencontré la phrase suivante :

> Ainsi, si tu es sourd mais **que** tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap en est estompé.

Pourquoi dit-on « que » là ? Est-ce que c’est pour éviter la répétition du mot « si » ? Est-ce que le verbe « portes » est bien au subjonctif là ?  Pourriez-vous donner d’autres exemples d’un tel usage ?

Comment: Il y a un autre exemple ici: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/when-is-que-needed-after-mais. Est-ce que ça répond à ta question ?

Answer (score 4):

Oui, **que** joue le rôle de **si** dans cette phrase, comme déjà répondu [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/when-is-que-needed-after-mais).

La version avec deux **si** sonne mal :

> Ainsi, si tu es sourd mais si tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap en est estompé.

Le verbe **porter** est probablement à l'indicatif comme le sont les autres verbes de la phrase.

---

Source [MANUEL DE LA GRAMMAIRE FRANÇAISE - Gabriel Wyler](http://gabrielwyler.com/page590.html):

> Dans la coordination de deux prémisses introduites par **si**, la conjonction de la deuxième prémisse peut être remplacée par la pro-conjonction **que**. Le subjonctif est facultatif dans la seconde prémisse.
>
> ?si vous venez et si je ne suis pas là →
>   si vous venez et que je ne sois/suis pas là
>
> si vous avez déjà consulté les liens indiqués ci-dessus, mais que vous devez prendre contact avec nous
>
> - La substitution de **que** à la deuxième conjonction est possible quelle que soit la nuance de **si**. La conjonction **si** peut avoir une valeur conditionnelle, temporelle ou semi-concessive.
> - La substitution est possible quel que soit le type logique de la coordination (**et**, **ou**, **mais**, etc.).
> - La substitution est possible quel que soit le temps des propositions coordonnées. Par exemple, si les deux prémisses sont irréelles, la première sera au plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif et la deuxième au plus-que-parfait du subjonctif : **si vous étiez venu et que je n'eusse pas été là**.

Comment: Pourquoi il y a un point d'interrogation devant _si_ ?

Comment: @suiiurisesse C'est une convention. Un ? indique une forme douteuse, comme * indique une forme fautive/inutilisée.

Comment: Il me semble que "Si vous venez et si je ne suis pas là" devient acceptable si on marque une pause nette après et si vous venez : Si vous venez — et si je ne suis pas là — …"

Comment: @Fólkvangr Lui seul le sait...

Comment: @Fólkvangr On ne sait rien sur lui, aucune biographie. C'est peut être un pseudonyme, ou un groupe de grammairiens, qui sait... On trouve quelques références comme celle-ci: [la grammaire de Gabriel Wyler: une grammaire linguistique du français, très complète. Plus je la découvre et plus je suis émerveillé par sa finesse et les exemples fournis. Mais ce n'est pas une grammaire pour débuter !](http://alpage.inria.fr/frmgwiki/wiki/liste-des-liens-externes-de-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence-pour-la-langue-fran%C3%A7aise)

Answer (score 1):

Le mot « que » permet d'incorporer une proposition à valeur de complétive. Il suffit de comparer la phrase originale avec la phrase réduite pour s'en apercevoir.

> Tu es sourd mais tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap <s>en</s> est estompé.
>   *Si* tu es sourd mais *que* tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap <s>en</s> est estompé.

On peut reformuler l'expression de façon équivalente.

> Tu es sourd mais doté d'un appareil auditif, ton handicap est estompé.
>   Si tu es sourd mais doté d'un appareil auditif, ton handicap est estompé.

L'expression « si tu es sourd et aveugle ... » vient confirmer l'affirmation précédente.

Les phrases suivantes sont incorrectes grammaticalement (mauvaise syntaxe) : les termes « mais, si, et » sont des conjonctions dans le contexte. D'ailleurs ces phrases n'ont aucun sens.

> *Si* tu es sourd **mais** *si* tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap <s>en</s> est estompé.
>   *Si* tu es sourd **et** *si* tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap <s>en</s> est estompé.

Enfin, on n'a aucune équivalence entre les termes « que » et « si ».

Answer (score 0):

Je reprends cette phrase "Ainsi, si tu es sourd mais que tu portes un appareil auditif, ton handicap en est estompé." Je trouve que c'est mal dit et peu clair. J'imagine que l'auteur de ces lignes veut donner un exemple d'une situation dans laquelle l'utilisation d'un appareil permet de compenser un handicap.

Reprenons avec un phrase complète.

"Il me semble que dans bien des situations, un handicap peut être très atténué par l'utilisation d'une aide technique. Par exemple, si vous êtes atteint de surdité, un appareil auditif vous permettra de recouvrer une audition presque normale dans la plupart des cas".

Evidemment une surdité neurologique grave ne pourra être corrigée par aucun appareil et l'auteur, s'il a écrit cela, est un peu imprudent et trop optimiste dans son pronostic de soulagement. Il pensait sans doute à une sorte de presbyacousie, souvent liée à l'âge du sujet, une affection qui en règle générale est très atténuée par l'usage d'un appareil, à condition évidemment que les sources sonores ne soient pas trop multiples et que le bruit environnant reste modéré.

Comment: @Folkvangr Votre commentaire est mesquin et agressif.

Comment: @Bazin Au contraire je trouve ce commentaire constructif. Vous etes vraiment hors sujet, et il est normal et sain de vous le signaler.